# Pointing to Static Class Member

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11

```
class A
{
static int x;
};
```

How to get the Address of `x` using pointer-to-member ?

Comment: x is not a member. So you can't. A member of an instance requires the use of this pointer to access it. There is no such concept with static members.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since it's static, this should be this syntax:

```
int *px = &A::x;  //x is static member
```

For non-static member, this is the syntax:

```
 int A::*py = &A::y; //y is non-static member
```

---

Example:

```
struct A
{
  static int x;
  int y;
};

int A::x=100;

int main() {
        int *px = &A::x;
        int A::*py = &A::y;

        A a;
        a.y = 200;

        cout << *px << endl;   //used just like normal pointers
        cout << a.*py << endl; //note how the pointer-to-member is used!
        cout << a.y << endl;   //a.*py and a.y are equivalent!
        return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
100
200
200
```

Demo : http://ideone.com/0xSdW

Note the the differences between pointer to static members, and pointer to non-static members, and how they're used!

Answer (score 0):

You can use *&A::x*. But remember to mark as public the variable and there will be only one X for all instances of the class.